# drawing image to bigger bitmap

Tags: c#, image, drawing, bitmap

Basically I want to stretch smaller image (i.e. 300x300 to bigger one i.e. 500x500) without space or black background.

I have a bitmap (let's say width 500px, and height 500px). How to draw another (smaller) image on that bitmap so it takes whole bitmap?

I already know how to create bitmap (i.e. `var bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500);`) and get the image - it can be loaded from file (i.e. `var image = Image.FromFile(...);`) or obtained from some other source.

Answer (score 20):

See the documentation for [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx). You can specify source and destination rectangles.

Example code:

```
Image i = Image.FromFile(fileName); // This is 300x300
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(500, 500);

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    g.DrawImage(i, 0, 0, 500, 500);
}
```

To use code make sure to add reference to System.Drawing assembly and add `using System.Drawing` to the file.

Comment: any particular reason that you see for why it isn't working? an error? what happens when you run the code?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following:

```
public Image ImageZoom(Image image, Size newSize)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(image, newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

And choose from one of the available [InterpolationModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx).